# How to structure jersey paths to avoid large classes

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I am building a restful api which is very user centric. This means that each request starts with the user: `api.test.com/rest/user/{user_id}`. Starting from this /user path there is a large variety of resources one can get about the user. As an example

```
api.test.com/rest/user/{user_id}/case
api.test.com/rest/user/{user_id}/picture
api.test.com/rest/user/{user_id}/anSoOn
```

With jersey I create a class which I annotate with @Path("user"). Now I have to add all my rest paths, which starts with `/user` in this class (in this example case, picture, anSoOn). This will blow up my user class immensely because on all resources I will also provide all crude operations. Is there a way in jersey to split the subpaths `/user/{user_id}/case` and so on up?

EDIT: Thanks to Lutz Horn for his answer. I want to add some more information:

operations about `/case` and `/user` should also be possible. Which would lead to creating classes for `@Path("/user")`, `@Path("/case")` and `@Path("/user/{userid}/case")`. It would be nice if one could create only two classes in this case:  `@Path("/user"), @Path("/case")`. But I guess that is not possible ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very legitimate question... I too have developed very long classes after defining very big root resources (with many "sub-resources") per class... By root resource I mean the `@Path` resource declaration on the class definition.

Here is what I have just tested, and possibly is a good "pattern" to better design and organize (sub-)"resource" classes. Basically the idea is to create a root resource (per class) at a more finer grained level (let's call it "sub-resource"), in your case:

- api.test.com.rest.user.Case.java class for `/rest/user/{user_id}/case`, containing methods to perform all CRUD operations on this "sub-resource";
- api.test.com.rest.user.Picture.java class for `/rest/user/{user_id}/picture`, containing methods to perform all CRUD operations on this "sub-resource"...

So basically you could organize your classes in packages per resource (e.g.: `api.test.com.rest.user.*` package would contain a class per each "sub-resource" of the resource "user").

In the "sub-resource" classes you would get the following type of construction:

```
@Path("/user/{user_id}/case")
public class Case { 

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public UserCase getUserCase(@PathParam("user_id") String userID) {
   ...
   }

   // all other CRUD operations on "user/user_id/case"
```

As you can see the "method" handling the GET does not have a `@Path`... you will only do the CRUD operations on the `@Path` declared at the "class" level... these operations also take the `user_id` from there.

There may be situations where you in these classes you need to put together more than the "sub-resource" CRUD operations... but this design should allow a better division of your code (when compared with the "big classes").

HTH!

Comment: Did you try this? I suppose it allows to tackle your concern: "It would be nice if one could create only two classes in this case: @Path("/user"), @Path("/case")."... i.e., it should be possible to create the two classes `Case` and `User`, although the `Case` class will probably need to be `@Path("/user/{user_id}/case")`.